# Map in an iFrame - open hyperlink from infoWindow in the calling page

Tags: google-maps, javascript, html, domains

I've got a Google Map being served inside an iFrame on a page (eg xxx.com/PageWithMap.html)

The code for the Google map sits on another domain (eg yyy.com/MapCode.html)

So it looks like this on xxx.com/PageWithMap.html:

```
<iframe src="yyy.com/MapCode.html"></iframe>
```

The markers in the map show an infoWindow which contains a hyperlink to a new page on the first site (eg `<a href="xxx.com/photo1.html">photo link</a>`)

How can I force the hyperlink to change the first page? That is, xxx.com/PageWithMap.html should navigate to xxx.com/photo1.html

I'm finding that xxx.com/photo1.html opens *inside* the iFrame on xxx.com/PageWithMap.html if I simply click the hyperlink.

Searching on StackOverflow suggests using `window.top.location.href` or `target="_parent"` or `target="_top"` but I can't get it to work. Is there an added complication since the hyperlink is within a Google Map infoWindow?

Let me know if the above description isn't clear - unfortunately I can't share the actual site yet but I may be able to make a mockup if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: I should have added that the parent site is a WordPress page. This may complicate matters as I won't necessarily have full access to run scripts etc on the page.

Comment: i have the exact same interest! the customized googlemap is located inside an iframe. i would like to click upon the list of infowindows (leftside pane of googlemap) so that I can click through them all using only one NEXT-Button. This button would have to be located in the parent-window of course... any Idea on how to realize this without API? and if that is supposedly not possible, then how would you do it with API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is quite popular and the article referenced below provides a great explanation as to why you can't (and shouldn't) do cross-site scripting *ever*.
It also shows how to circumvent in a legal and safe way the problem:

http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ***not tested*** proposition :

```
window.opener.parent.location= "xxx.com/photo1.html"
```

If it still does not work, could you please provide an online sample.

By the way, this question could also go on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [ProWebmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) since it's pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that an iframe can't manipulate its parent document due to security reasons. You will have to use [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) in order to include the map as a part of your site, instead of an iframe.

EDIT: looks like I'm wrong. I did a quick test, a link with target="_parent" inside of an iframe loaded in a parent document.